# Dynamically aligned Variable Sized cells in a Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

What I have to do is draw variable size cells from left to right. Since the data is from server, its length can't be determined (thus the need for variable sized cells.). I have tried the gridviews, tablelayouts but they align them in an order. What I want is something like this:

[a sample http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/4136/samplejy.png](http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/4136/samplejy.png)

the most important thing is they are kind of aligned in a column (though one column can have further multiple columns) but there is no row as such..the cells are in some kind of array which I have to align from left to right and not from top to bottom.. If anyone has tried anything like this it will be very helpful.. thanks

Comment: is there any maximum number of sub-coloumn per coloumn? like in your picture there are 3 coloumn and the coloumn 1 and 3 have sub coloumn

Comment: Consider it as 2.. actually what I would like to have is something like six columns with option to combine 2 of them into one based on the requirement..for example if the cell has a attribute size of 2 then it will be the size of two sub columns..something like that but most importantly there must not be any row as such.